# How can i find a value in a map using binders only

Tags: c++, stl

Searching in the second value of a map i use somthing like the following:

```
typedef std::map<int, int> CMyList;
static CMyList myList;

template<class t> struct second_equal
{
    typename typedef t::mapped_type mapped_type;
    typename typedef t::value_type value_type;

    second_equal(mapped_type f) : v(f)   {};
    bool operator()(const value_type &a) { return a.second == v;};

    mapped_type v;
};
...    
int i = 7;
CMyList::iterator it = std::find_if(myList.begin(), myList.end(), 
                                    second_equal<CMyList>(i));
```

Question: How can i do such a find in a single line without supplying a self written template?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a selector to select the first or the second element from the value_type that you get from the map.
Use a binder to bind the value (i) to one of the arguments of the `std::equal_to` function.
Use a composer to use the output of the selector as the other argument of the equal_to function.

```
//stl version
CMyList::iterator it = std::find_if(
    myList.begin(), 
    myList.end(), 
    std::compose1(
        std::bind2nd(equal_to<CMyList::mapped_type>(), i), 
        std::select2nd<CMyList::value_type>())) ;

//Boost.Lambda or Boost.Bind version
CMyList::iterator it = std::find_if(
    myList.begin(), 
    myList.end(), 
    bind( &CMyList::mapped_type::second, _1)==i);
```

Comment: is it possible to shorten this with boost::bind?

Comment: Spot on, but so unreadable and messy I would recommend code clean-up in a code review. Isn't there a better way with boost binders ?

Comment: Erm, isn't that  Boost.Bind, not Lambda?

Comment: @sbi For this example the Boost.Bind syntax is the same as the Boost.Lambda syntax

Comment: I was looking for a plain STL-solution and your first sample actually is it. But i have to admit that i rather stay with my homegrown template than nesting 3 STL calls into a parameter. Its much easier to type as well as to understand.

Comment: std::compose1 and std::select2nd are not part of the standard, it's an SGI extension.

Comment: For gcc select2nd seems to be in the namespace __gnu_cxx.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to be off, voluntarily. The problem with lambda's is that (apart from C++0x) you cannot actually use something like `_.second` at the moment.

Personally, I thus use:

```
template <class Second>
class CompareSecond
{
public:
  CompareSecond(Second const& t) : m_ref(t) {} // actual impl use Boost.callparams
  template <class First>
  bool operator()(std::pair<First,Second> const& p) const { return p.second == m_ref; }
private:
  Second const& m_ref;
};
```

Which I combine with:

```
template <class Second>
CompareSecond<Second> compare_second(Second const& t)
{
  return CompareSecond<Second>(t);
}
```

In order to get automatic type deduction.

And this way I can just write

```
CMyList::iterator it = std::find_if(myList.begin(), myList.end(), compare_second(i));
```

True, it does not use binders.

But at least, mine is readable and easily understandable, which beats the crap out of clever trickery in my opinion.

**Note**:
actually I went as far as wrapping STL algorithms to take full containers, so it would be:

```
 CMyList::iterator it = toolbox::find_if(myList, compare_second(i));
```

which (imho) is clearly as readable as you can get without the `auto` keyword for type inference.

Comment: I like the note. I have a header called `container.h` that does this for most of the algorithms in a separate namespace called, you guested it, `container`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Boost Lambda](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/lambda.html)

```
CMyList::iterator it = std::find_if(
      myList.begin(), myList.end(), 
      boost::lambda::bind(&CMyList::value_type::second, boost::lambda::_1) == i);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can turn this problem around and just write your own algorithm and use it instead.  This way you are not stuck with writing lots of little functors.

```
template <typename Iter, typename T>
Iter find_second(Iter first, Iter last, T value) {
    while (first != last) {
        if (first->second == value) {
            return first;
        }
        ++first;
    }
    return first;
}
```

**Note** this isn't tested or even compiled.

It seems to me that solving this with binders is just asking for lots of ugly code.  What you are really asking for is a new algorithm so just add the algorithm.  With that said, I would probably end up implementing something like [Matthieu M.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728847/how-can-i-find-a-value-in-a-map-using-binders-only/1728910#1728910) came up with.

Comment: I disagree with this approach, nonetheless the name you picked for your algorithm is very misleading. If I didn't look at the source code I would guess it returns the second match of a value.

Comment: @daniel: didn't even think of that when I named it... it does look a little like something that should mimic `find_first`.